HF transformers: ValueError: Unable to create tensor
I was following this guide for text classification
and i gotten and error:
ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length.

I tried adding padding=True and truncation=True to preprocessing_tokenizer()  but the same error arises.
These answers did not help me that much either.

I can't just copy the preprocess_function from the guide and have to expand on the function like this:
def preprocess_function(examples):
   label_mapping = {'i': 0, 'g': 1}
   inputs = tokenizer(
    examples["text"], truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="pt"
)
   labels = [label_mapping[label] for label in examples["labels"]]
   labels = torch.tensor(labels)
   return {
    "input_ids": inputs["input_ids"],
    "attention_mask": inputs["attention_mask"],
    "labels": labels,
   }

